# Can I colour one element in a BIM with multiple colours?

Tags: autodesk-forge, bim

I am looking into ways to colour an element in my BIM file (Walls, Floors etc.) with multiple colours. The idea is that when I have a wall or floor through multiple rooms, I want to colour that wall based on the Room data. However the Room data can be different and so the elements should get one colour in one room, and another colour in the other room.

I have seen a video from Autodesk Forge, where a floor got a shade from green to red, based on how good WiFi reception. It was said that it was just a texture over a surface. Would something like this be possible using Autodesk Forge? Or any other possibilities?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sjors, welcome :). Stackoverflow works best when you try to code something and then ask questions on that code that didn't work as you intended. Would you share what you have already tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [setThemingColor](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive) method. For Rooms, make sure to get the [master view](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces). For advanced coloring, please refere to [shaders](https://forge.autodesk.com/zh-hans/node/1718).